# Dynamic Navigation Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, hyperlink

I am working on a project where I have a horizontal navigation bar with 6 links, 3 of which are part of a sub navigation in the same horizontal bar. The links are represented with icons. I am looking for the easiest way to dynamically change the sub navigation when clicking on one of the main navigation icons.

```
[ Home - Search ]{ home1 - home2 - home3 }[ Add ]
```

when search is selected, it changes to:

```
[ Home - Search ]{ search1 - search2 - search3 }[ Add ]
```

This is the HTML for the bar currently. The links for the replacement icons have not been produced as it currently breaks the structure.

```
<nav id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <div id="mainNav">
            <li><a id="activeLink" class="homeLink" href="#">Home<a/></li>
            <li><a class="searchLink" href=#>Search<a/></li>
        </div>
        <div id="subNav">
            <li><a class="feedLink" href=#>Feed<a/></li>            
            <li><a class="messagesLink" href=#>Messages<a/></li>
            <li><a class="connectionsLink" href=#>Connections<a/></li>
        </div>
        <div id="mainNav">
            <li><a class="addLink" href=#>Add<a/></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="searchBar"></nav>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're markup isn't valid. The `div`s need to be outside of the `ul`s.

Comment: Also, none of you `a` closing tags are correct. `<a/>` should be `</a>`.

Comment: Thank you for these comments, I've made these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you need to get real clever with it. Just put them together and toggle a `.hidden` class:

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="activeLink" class="homeLink" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="searchLink" href="#">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="subNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="feedLink" href="#">Feed</a></li>            
                <li><a class="messagesLink" href="#">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a class="connectionsLink" href="#">Connections</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="searchNav" class="hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Search 1</a></li>            
                <li><a href="#">Search 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="addLink" href="#">Add</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $subnavs = $('#subNav, #searchNav'),
        $search = $('#mainNav .searchLink');

    $search.click(function(){
        $subnavs.toggleClass('hidden');

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/eJm2z/1

Note, that horribly ugly menu styling is just for demonstration only...

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration, it was very helpful, I may end up using a variation of this. The goal is really to be able to access the subnav of search from anywhere on the site without reloading the page. How would I make it so it isn't a "toggle"? For instance, hitting the homeLink would cause the home subnav to appear instead of toggling the search subnav on and off by selecting searchLink.

Comment: Are you talking about a dedicated search subnav-opening button and a dedicated home link subnav-opening top-level menu item? So if you click `Search` more than once, you only open the `Search` subnav and hide the `Home`, and vice versa? Or hide the `Search` nav button on show, and show when it's subnav is hidden?

Comment: I mean, if I select Home, it will show the home subnav items and if I select Search, it'll show search subnav items. All without having to go to a new page.

Comment: However, I'm trying to implement it and it simply is not working. I am not sure why.

Comment: Without seeing what you've got that doesn't work, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0):

This code modifies each link with a new class and new text based on the titles passed in to `responder`:

```
var responder = function(components) {
    return function() {
        $.each($("#subNav a"), function(index, element) {
            $(element).text(components[index]);
            $(element).attr("class", components[index]+"Link");
        });
    }
};
$(".homeLink").click(responder(["home1", "home2", "home3"]))
$(".searchLink").click(responder(["search1", "search2", "search3"]))
```

Adding more options would be as easy as attaching `responder([titles...])` to a `click` event;